# Who is making the Modern Family documentary?

Tags: modern-family

Modern Family is filmed like somebody is making a documentary. Who is making the documentary that is Modern Family? And Why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Jaime Weinman has the 411](http://www.macleans.ca/culture/who-on-earth-are-they-talking-to/):

> In the original pilot script for Modern Family, the creators included
>   a subplot explaining why the show’s three wacky families were being
>   filmed documentary-style. The idea was that **the interconnected
>   families were the subject of a movie being made by a Dutch exchange
>   student; he was going to have a backstory and fall in love with one of
>   the regulars.**
>
> But by the time the show made it to air, the documentary
>   filmmaker was nowhere to be seen, and as Modern Family has grown into
>   the biggest hit comedy of the season, the characters have never shown
>   any awareness that they’re being filmed. Co-creator Steven Levitan
>   (Just Shoot Me!) made it official in an interview with the Television
>   Critics Association, saying that the presence of the documentarian
>   “felt like an appendage, like we didn’t need it.” **Modern Family is now
>   a show that uses documentary film techniques but never bothers to
>   explain why; that’s why Levitan calls it “a family show done
>   documentary-style.”**

[From the New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/01/23/fashion/23THISLIFE.html?pagewanted=all):

> **Originally “Modern Family” centered on a Dutch filmmaker who had been
>   an exchange student with the Pritchetts in high school**. The writers
>   dropped the character because he was cumbersome, and, as Mr. Levitan
>   said, “because I don’t like the people who allow cameramen to sit
>   around their house all day while they raise their kids.”
>
> But two crucial elements remain. First, characters in the middle of a
>   scene will often glance at the camera, a disconcerting aside that has
>   the effect of making the viewer feel both like a part of the family
>   and an observer. A result is a feeling of “Who’s laughing at whom
>   here?” that echoes the larger reality-show surrealism that surrounds
>   the Kardashians, “The Housewives” and Sarah Palin.
>
> Second, the characters in “Modern Family” all offer confessional
>   interviews directly to an unidentified cameraperson. Jay may say he
>   pretends to love his daughter’s blueberry pie, but he really hates it.
>   Or Mitchell may say, as he does in this episode, “Cameron has it in
>   his head that I don’t listen to him, but I do.”
>
> The idea of internal monologue is hardly new — think of any ballad in
>   a Broadway musical. What’s new is that we all engage in this sort of
>   running narrative of our lives, rushing off after dinner (or coitus)
>   to share our confessions on Twitter or Facebook.
>
> [...]
>
> As Mr. Lloyd said: “The interviews are a chance to have characters
>   more honestly express things than they might openly do in a scene with
>   someone. So we get a laugh from the contrast between what they’re
>   really feeling and what they were willing to admit they were feeling
>   in the scene.”