# Is the mockumentary format diegetic in Parks and Rec?

Tags: analysis, parks-and-recreation

In some mockumentary shows, like 'The Office', the mockumentary format is diegetic, because there is actually a documentary being filmed in-universe.  In others, the mockumentary format is extra-diegetic, and simply a story telling device allowing us to see the thoughts of the characters, like a modern-day soliloquy; see, *eg*, 'Modern Family'.

In 'Parks and Rec', is there an in-universe documentary being filmed, or is it just the format of the program behind the fourth wall?

Comment: WRT Modern Family it kinda was: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35589/who-is-making-the-modern-family-documentary

Comment: Near-duplicate of [Who is filming the Pawnee Parks and Recreation department?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/63175) from the "related questions" sidebar.

Comment: @Harsh it's a great term. I'm used to hearing it regarding a soundtrack or music, where any music the audience hears is happening in-universe. (Commonly shown when the actor turns off a radio and the soundtrack cuts off as well.)

Comment: @BruceWayne ah! that's a good example and widely encountered one too! Reminds me of Baby Driver; the movie essentially revolved around what you said!

Comment: As someone who works in local government, what makes you think that it is a mockumentary? Joking aside, my boss couldn't watch the show because it was too much like her real job at times.

Answer (score 25):

**There is only reason to assume it's non-diegetic.**

- The motivation for filming is never disclosed.
- The characters never interact with what would be an in-universe film crew - they only address them (thus, rather, the viewer through this particular technique).
- The 'film crew' is everywhere it needs to be, and present at any time something interesting happens, including during private situations that cannot be rehearsed.

(I can't think of specific examples right now, but will update when I remember.)

Comment: Is The Office unique in that the existence of the documentary was revealed (in the finale)? I've always assumed that the reason we never see the crew in most mockumentary shows is that either the characters are told not to address them, or those interactions are all edited out.

Comment: @Barmar the existence of the documentary is revealed early on. Also in the last season there is a plot with a member of the documentary crew(Bryan i think)

Comment: @Barmar, also in the Office where people were avoiding the filming crew on purpose, and long distance microphones were used to overhear the conversation.

Answer (score 21):

In the pilot episode, Ron asks "did you guys get a grant to do this" ('this' referring to the filming), which as far as I can remember is the only moment in the show where the actual camera crew is referenced. Besides that, @Joachim is absolutely correct.

Comment: I remember that, now that you mention it :) That's a strange exception to what seems to be a very rigid rule for the rest of the series.

Comment: One other instance is in the episode "End of the World": Lucy kisses Tom, and a moment later Tom turns to a camera, points, and says "You saw that", then turns to another, points, and says "You saw that, too."

Comment: @KenBellows Right! I'm starting to think it's neither diegetic *or* non-diegetic, just a "camera crew ex machina" sort of thing :)